# Detaching content from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

In general, I have some kind of form on the page with multiple listeners. Those listeners are applied to all document (e.g. jQuery's $(document).on("click", "") and for now this can not be changed. I also need to show exactly the same (by structure) form in the modal, and that form shares all js code of main form on the screen. So these forms can not work together, when they both active, cause button click in second form, for example, triggers elements in the first. jQuery's detach is almost the simplest solution for this, but it also removes everything from screen, I want to avoid that.

Is there any way to detach contents from the HTML DOM without actual removing of contents from screen?

What I need is to temporarily disable all event listeners for some content on the page and also remove it from searching by js-library selectors (so, for example, jQuery should not find anything), but the content should still appear on the screen.

Is this actually possible?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Obviously, you wish to do this in order to allow something else to happen - what is that something? (Your questions is is known as an "X/Y problem", google it)

Comment: In general, I have some kind of form on the page with multiple listeners. Those listeners are applied to all document (e.g. jQuery's `$(document).on("click", "<selector>"`) and for now this can not be changed. I also need to show exactly the same form in the modal, and that form shares all js code of main form on the screen. So these forms can not work together, when they both active, cause button click in second form, for example, triggers elements in the first. jQuery's detach is almost the simplest solution for this, but it also removes everything from screen, I want to avoid that.

Comment: Well still looks like a XY problem. That's said, why cannot you just set disabled attribute or set a class (`disabled`) to filter it out, for e.g: `$(document).on("click", "<selector>:not(.disabled)", handler);`. Anyway, if you provide a simple MCVE, i guess there is better to do... Of course, you could just add a class to the specific form you want to disable: `$(document).on("click", "form:not(.disabled) :input", handler)`

Comment: Okay, so then duplicate the form - but don't clone it. The information is the same, but the form isn't. Just like human twins may appear identical, yet have different names I'd probably approach this task in the same manner.

Comment: @A.Wolff, yes, maybe. I didn't say, that this the only solution I was thinking of. I just wonder if such is possible, cause it seems to be the simplest (if it exists) and I did not face something like this before.

Comment: @GinoPane Just share minimalistic sample replicating your issue, or at lest relevant code used to bind event(s). For sure, there is better to do. Like said, the easiest one would be to toggle a class

Comment: maybe replace the form with a canvas?

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: you can't

Some leads to get close to your goal:

1. You could try to use shadow dom to remove a direct access to
   js-library selectors: they will need to use `::shadow` suffix to the
   selectors to find your content.
2. Detach your content, clone it, reattach it

   ```
   var $yourcontent = $(".yourcontentselector").detach();
   var $clone = $yourcontent.clone(); //clone the content but not events
   $clone.appendTo("body");
   //later
   $clone.remove();
   $yourcontent.appendTo("body");
   ```

I assumed you are using JQuery and your content is directly into the body.
Hope it can help

Comment: For point **2**, no because event is delegated to document level. From OP's comment: `Those listeners are applied to all document`

Comment: Yes you are right, it was just a lead. You Could stop these events or maybe just a css property `pointer-events:none` will work

Answer (score 0):

You could [deep-clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/importNode) the DOM into an iframe and display that until you need to re-attach/unhide the original content. You will also have to transfer the stylesheets since browsers do not support the [seamless](http://caniuse.com/#search=seamless) attribute yet.

Another option might be attaching a capturing event listener at the document level and stopping the event propagation if the target element matches the right selectors. But that won't stop selector-lookups. For that you could temporarily change the node IDs or classes.

> I also need to show exactly the same form in the modal, and that form shares all js code of main form on the screen. So these forms can not work together

Well, those forms should have unique names/IDs, having two forms of the same name or ID [is a violation of HTML spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#the-form-element).

And if they do have unique IDs or names then you can make your logic ID-based.

Comment: Yep, using of iframe is another solution I was thinking about.

Comment: You're completely right with this "having two forms of the same name or ID is a violation of HTML spec". And those forms actually have the same id. And code is written in such way, that making it ID-based will cause too many changes (for now it is better not to change initial codebase at all). That is why I'm looking for a, maybe, strange, but effective solution:)

Comment: your code is broken. you need to fix it instead of investing more time in crude workarounds.

Comment: I agree, actually it's not mine but I have to deal with it:) I prefer to think of it as a black box due to it's age and legacy nature. Unfortunately it's not an option for now to rewrite it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need that:

```
  var element = document.getElementById('element');
  var elementParent = document.getElementById('element-parent');
  elClone = element.cloneNode(true);
  console.log('cloned node', elClone);
  elementParent.removeChild(element);
  console.log('after removal: ', document.getElementById('element'));

   // ..... some time later

  elementParent.appendChild(elClone);
  console.log('after appending:' , document.getElementById('element'));
```

This removes all event listeners and 'hides' element from **live selection**.

Comment: This won't remove listener delegated to document level

Comment: The question was wether it removes all event listeners associated with the node with all the content temporarily, and it does. 

https://jsfiddle.net/rzpz7w7b/

There is however need to re-append eventlistener.

Comment: The question is uncomplete and badly asked for many reasons. In comments question, OP said he is delegating event thus your solution won't work in this case

Comment: Okay then, didn't see his comments as of that moment.

Comment: Ya that's why i said the question is uncomplete :)